# posting a form from one HTTPS to another HTTPS site causing security alert

Tags: asp.net, post, asp-classic, webforms, https

I need to post a string from a .NET site to a Classic ASP site which are hosted on the same server (different virtual directories).

https: //example.com/DOTNETSite/Sender.aspx

to

https: //example.com/ClassicASP/SomeFolder/Target.asp

Target.asp page has 3 ways to handle incoming data:

1. Form Post
2. Query String
3. Headers

I cant pass my data in query string. so that option is out. I am trying the Form post method by building a form on the server side and spitting out javascript code to do a form.submit(). But this is causing a internet explorer to throw a Security Alert for the user. We want to avoid this. Please let us know what is the best way to overcome this situation. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Do you have any mixed content somewhere? How do other browsers behave? For example Firefox, with the HTTP page warning properties kept to `true`: `security.warn_entering_secure`, `security.warn_leaving_secure`: you can set them by typing `about:config` in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are doing:

> your server ----> your client/browser ----> their server

Instead you should use:

> your server ----> your client/browser ----> your server ----> their server

That is (if it wasn't clear enough),  make it send the form to your own server.
When your server receives the form, it should send it to the target server.

On a basic level, this works. However, you may get issues if the user is supposed to be logged in on the 2nd server etc.

I'll try to illustrate an example in PHP:

File: *form.html*

```
<form action="send.php" method="post">
    ....
</form>
```

File: *send.php*

```
<?php
  $url='https://example.com/ClassicASP/SomeFolder/Target.asp';
  // create new cur connection
  $ch=curl_init();
  // tell curl target url
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  // tell curl we will be sending via POST
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  // tell it not to validate ssl cert
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  // tell it where to get POST variables from
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST); 
  // make the connection
  curl_exec($ch);
  // close connection
  curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. please, can u be more specific on this? as i understood, doing a form post via javascript is a wrong option. correct? just an fyi, i need this in asp.net c#

Comment: In some cases (like an IdP to an SP in SSO via Shibboleth), "your server ----> your client/browser ----> your server ----> their server" isn't desirable and "your server ----> your client/browser ----> their server" is, otherwise the second server may not be able to authenticate the browser directly and the first server could effectively be a man in the middle. Posting to another HTTPS normally works without warning.

Comment: @Bruno, that is why I said being man-in-the-middle may introduce other problems, however, as I said, on a basic level it works. @wortex, what I'm saying is, instead of making the user send the request to the target server, make your own server send the target request - after receiving the required data from the user's form first, of course.

Comment: can u guys provide some sample code for this? I tried this: Response.Write("<body onload=document.forms[0].submit();>");
Response.Write("<form name=\"Form\" method=post action=\"https://example.com/ClassicASP/SomeFolder/Target.asp\">");
Response.Write(string.Format("<input type=hidden name=\"postData\" value=\"{0}\">", "data"));
Response.Write("</form>");
Response.Write("</body>");
this works from localhost to the target, but when i deploy to prod with https, it throws me the security popup.

Comment: @wortex - No, you have to make your server do the HTTP(S) connection yourself! In PHP, we use CURL or Sockets, see what's the equivalent in ASP.